# Check If JavaScript Object Parameter Exist or Not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function with object parameter. How can i check if object parameter is set or not. When it not set it shows error.

```js
function run(params) {
    if (params.offsettop) {
        alert("offsettop is set");
    } else {
        alert("offsettop is not set");
    }
}
run();
```

Comment: `undefined` doesn't have a property `offsettop`, you need to pass something to the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be sure `params` isn't `null` or `undefined` (although you can get away with just checking if it's truthy). Then to truly check if the object property exists, use `in` (checks if the property exists on the object or any of its prototypes) or `.hasOwnProperty()` (just checks the object):

```
function run(params) {
    if (params && "offsettop" in params) {
        alert("offsettop is set");
    } else {
        alert("offsettop is not set");
    }
}
```

Example:

```js
function run(params) {
    if (params && "offsettop" in params) {
        console.log("offsettop is set: " + params.offsettop);
    } else {
        console.log("offsettop is not set");
    }
}
run();
run({offsettop: 0});
```

Other options for

```
if (params && "offsettop" in params) {
```

are

```
if (params != null && "offsettop" in params) {
```

Example:

```js
function run(params) {
    if (params != null && "offsettop" in params) {
        console.log("offsettop is set: " + params.offsettop);
    } else {
        console.log("offsettop is not set");
    }
}
run();
run({offsettop: 0});
```

and

```
if (typeof params == "object" && params && "offsettop" in params) {
```

Example:

```js
function run(params) {
    if (typeof params == "object" && params && "offsettop" in params) {
        console.log("offsettop is set: " + params.offsettop);
    } else {
        console.log("offsettop is not set");
    }
}
run();
run({offsettop: 0});
```

This is fundamentally different from `if (params && typeof params.offsettop === "undefined")` or `if (params && params.offsettop)` because it will determine whether the property exists reliably, whereas the `typeof` check fails with `{offsettop: undefined}` and the truthy check fails with `{offsettop: 0}` (and several other falsy values).

Answer (score 0):

First check if `params` is set, and later check if `params.offsettop` is set

```js
function run(params) {
  if (params && params.offsettop) {
    alert("offsettop is set");
  } else {
    alert("offsettop is not set");
  }
}
run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
function run(params) {
  if ((typeof params!= "undefined") && (typeof params.offsettop != "undefined")) 
  {
 alert("offsettop is set");
  }
  else {
 alert("offsettop is not set");
  }
}
run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Meet [`#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) function - it checks whether an *object* has the specified *property*.

See demo below:

```js
function run(params) {
  if (params && params.hasOwnProperty('offsettop')) {
    console.log("offsettop is set");
  } else {
    console.log("offsettop is not set");
  }
}
run({offsettop: 23});
run();
```

Answer (score 0):

Both can work, either:

```
function run(params) {

  if ( params && params.hasOwnProperty("offsettop" )) {
    alert("offsettop is set");
  } else {
    alert("offsettop is not set");
  }
}
run();
```

Or like @Justinas wrote: `if ( params && params.offsettop )` though I wonder why that wasn't marked as "answer"

Answer (score 0):

We can check by below method whether a variable is object or not and then it contains the given property

```
const run = (params) => { 
 if (typeof params === 'object' && params !== null && 
  Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(params, 'offsettop')) {
  console.log('Params is an object and has property named offsettop');
 }
 else {
  console.log('Failed')
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write just below code.

```js
function run(params) {
  if (params && params['offsettop']) {
    alert("offsettop is set");
  } else {
    alert("offsettop is not set");
  }
}
run();
run({offsettop:25})
```

Answer (score -3):

```
  if(params && typeof params.offsettop == 'undefined'){
      //parameter is not set
  }
```